# How to manually iterate over array/object without `foreach` and without `for` with PHP

Tags: php, json

There is this library `https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine` (PHP) that allows me to read huge JSON files without loading the entire file to memory. It works great and the way I read the JSON is like this:

```
$temp = \JsonMachine\JsonMachine::fromFile("teste.json");

foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {

    echo $value;

}
```

The problem is that I cant use `foreach`, I need to only read the JSON as I need. For example, I tried the code below everytime I need to retrieve an element from the array:

```
echo next($temp);
```

However it returns and empty string. If I use `var_dump(current($temp))` it returns this:

```
object(JsonMachine\StreamBytes)#2 (1) { ["stream":"JsonMachine\StreamBytes":private]=> resource(10) of type (stream) }
```

Using the `foreach` loop works perfectly, but I cant use it, I need to retrieve the elements as I need. How can I do that?

Comment: You seem to be looking for a generator. Generators can yield results as and when needed.

Comment: @CBroe I dont want to read random elements, I want to read one by one, in sequential order BUT I want to read the elements as I need, not in a foreach loop.

Comment: @jibsteroos do you have any idea of any other library that allows me to read JSON in PHP one element at a time?

Comment: @Rob Ruchte do you have any idea of any other library that allows me to read JSON in PHP one element at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This class already provides a generator, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$temp = \JsonMachine\JsonMachine::fromFile("teste.json");
$iterator = $temp->getIterator();
$firstItem = $iterator->current();
$iterator->next();
$secondItem = $iterator->current();
$iterator->next();
$thirdItem = $iterator->current();
```

[Edit] Looks like `JsonMachine::getIterator()` returns a chained generator, so just change that second line to this:

```
$iterator = $temp->getIterator()->getIterator();
```

Comment: If your solution works that will be amazing!!! But your code resulted in this error ` Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method JsonMachine\Parser::current()`

Comment: AMAZING! Thank you!

Comment: When you reach the end, `$iterator->current()` will return `NULL` and `$iterator->valid()` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexHowansky. This will be fixed in v1.0.0.  Only one `getIterator()` call will be needed. See https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md